# Fastest equivalent of comparing all elements of array

Tags: c#, performance, linq, optimization

What is the fastest equivalent in C#/LINQ to compare all combination of elements of an array like so and add them to a bucket if they are not in a bucket. AKA. How could I optimize this piece of code in C#.

```
// pseudocode

List<T> elements = { .... }
HashSet<T> bucket = {}

foreach (T element in elements)

    foreach (var myelemenet in elements.Where(e => e.id != element.id))
    {
        if (!element.notInTheList)
        {
               _elementIsTheSame = element.Equals(myelement);

               if (_elementIsTheSame)
               {
                   // append element to a bucket
                   
                   if (!elementIsInTheBucket(bucket, element))
                   {
                       element.notInTheList = true;
                       addToBucket(bucket, element);     
                   }
                }
            }
      }
 }
 // takes about 150ms on a fast workstation with only 300 elements in the LIST!
```

The final order of the elements in the bucket is important

Comment: What do you mean by  "bucket"? Are you trying to implement something like `DisctinctBy` from MoreLINQ?

Comment: an array where the order of the elements is important.

Comment: "If not element not in bucket, then add" - you may want to fix some naming

Comment: Can you move that "in bucket" test to within the outer loop? Within the loop over all elements, you are again looping over the same elements: O(n^2)

Comment: Second foreach loop you are comparing with elements.property. Is this correct ?

Comment: ups. yep i forgot to add the True statement. fixed now

Comment: It's really unclear what you are trying to do with this pseudo code, and we are not expected to guess. The slow parts obviously are the inner loops -   `Where(e => e.property != element.property)` for sure, and eventually `elementIsInTheBucket` if it contains linear search. But if `mylelement.property != element.property`, I don't see how `element.Equals(myelement)` could be true.

Comment: lets say element.property is an unique ID of the object

Comment: I fixed it now .

Comment: The only way element.Equals(element) is ever true is if you have overrriden equals.  Is this the case?

Comment: yes i have but its not relevant which comparison

Comment: Well, it makes it very hard for us to figure out what is going on in the provided code.

Comment: In fact there are three methods and one entity that are key to your functionality that we are having to guess what does.  The overriden equals, elementIsInTheBucket, and addToBucket.

Comment: Default guess for equals is that it is not overriden, which would make your method a no-op, but you say that it is overriden so you are selecting elements based on some criteria that we do not see.

Comment: elementIsInTheBucket, I would guess that this is just Enumerable.Contains, but why not use Enumerable.Contains?  So my guess might be wrong.

Comment: addToBucket, I would guess this just calls _bucket.Add - But why have a custom method for that?  Again, my guess might be wrong.

Comment: the criteria is a simple commutable comparison. it means element1.Equals(element2) is the same as element2.Equals(element1)

Comment: Also, I am forced to assume that _bucket is a list, but it could be essentially any other collection, or not even a collection at all.

Comment: I would like to optimize this code before optimizing stuff around this

Comment: Is the following bahavior from your code the correct behavior?

The first element in an equivalence class will be added to the bucket last unless it's the only element in said class.  If it is the only element in the class it will not be added to the bucket.

Comment: If "the final order of the elements in the bucket is important" then a HashSet is not the right tool for the job as sets are unordered.

Comment: makes sense . but with order i mean also how they are stacked in the bucket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
elements.GroupBy(x=>x).SelectMany(x=>x);
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/yZ9JDp

This works because GroupBy preserves order.

Note that this puts the first element of each equivalence class first.  Your code puts the first element last, and skips classes with just a single element.
Skipping the classes with just a single element can be done with a where before the SelectMany.

```
elements.GroupBy(x=>x).Where(x=>x.Skip(1).Any()).SelectMany(x=>x);
```

Getting the first element last is a bit more tricky, but I suspect it's a bug in your code so I will not try to write it out.

Depending on how you use the result you might want to throw a ToList() at the end.

Comment: As a side note I have used groupBy(x=>x) before (to group according to an overriden equals).  And I have also used SelectMany(x=>x) to flatten nested lists.  I think this is the first time I have done both in the same line.

Comment: with GroupBy preserves order do you mean that both the "pseudo" code and groupBy will put the elements in the bucket in the same order ?

Comment: and why Skip(1) is needed ? can you explain this ?

Comment: Skip(1).Any() is a way to write Count() greater than 1 that does not go through the entire collection.

Comment: Yes.  The above will return the elements in the same order as your pseudo code, with the exception that the first element in each class will not be placed last.  - See the link to the fiddle for actual order.

Comment: in my particular implementation i had to use a Distinct(x => x) at the the of this GroupBy Statement but I'll accept this answer since you added also the fiddle and You answered to my questions.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're effectively after `DistinctBy`? Which can be simulated with something like:

```cs
var list = new List<MainType>();
var known = new HashSet<PropertyType>();
foreach (var item in source)
{
    if (known.Add(item.TheProperty))
        list.Add(item);
}
```

You now have a list of the items taking the first only when there are duplicates via the selected property, preserving order.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from what you did you need is these pieces.

```
var multipleIds=elements.GroupBy(x => x.id)
              .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
              .Select(y => y.Key);
  var distinctIds=elements.Select(x=>x.id).Distinct();
  var distinctElements=elements.Where(x=>distinctIds.Contains(x.id));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the intent is to find the fastest solution, as the StackOverflow title suggests, then I would consider using CSharp's [Parallel.ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=netframework-4.8) to perform a *map and reduce*.

For example:

```cs
var resultsCache = new IRecord[_allRecords.Length];
var resultsCount = 0;

var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 // use an appropriate value
};

Parallel.ForEach(
                 _allRecords,
                 parallelOptions,
          // Part1: initialize thread local storage
          () => { return new FilterMapReduceState(); },

          // Part2: define task to perform
          (record, parallelLoopState, index, results) =>
          {
              if (_abortFilterOperation)
              {
                  parallelLoopState.Break();
              }

              if (strategy.CanKeep(record))
              {
                  resultsCache[index] = record;
                  results.Count++;
              }
              else
              {
                  resultsCache[index] = null;
              }

              return results;
          },
          // Part3: merge the results
          (results) =>
          {
              Interlocked.Add(ref resultsCount, results.Count);
          }
);
```

where

```cs
class FilterMapReduceState
{
    public FilterMapReduceState()
    {
        this.Count = 0;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the number of records that meet the search criteria.
    /// </summary>
    internal int Count { get; set; }
}
```